# how to use multiple callbacks in jpicker

Tags: jquery, color-picker, jquery-callback, jpicker

I would like to use jpicker to modify multiple elements, this is the code for a single element (#body02), is it possible to create an array for each element?

```
   $(document).ready(
function()
{
  var LiveCallbackElement = $('#body02'),
      LiveCallbackButton = $('#LiveButton');  // you don't want it searching this

                                     // on every live callback!!!
  $('#Callbacks').jPicker(
    {window:{position:{x:'screenCenter',y:'200'}}},
    function(color, context)
    {
      var all = color.val('all');
      alert('Color chosen - hex: ' + (all && '#' + all.hex || 'none') +
        ' - alpha: ' + (all && all.a + '%' || 'none'));
      $('#body02').css(
        {
          backgroundColor: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
        }); // prevent IE from throwing exception if hex is empty
    },
    function(color, context)
    {
      if (context == LiveCallbackButton.get(0)) alert('Color set from button');
      var hex = color.val('hex');
      LiveCallbackElement.css(
        {
          backgroundColor: hex && '#' + hex || 'transparent'
        }); // prevent IE from throwing exception if hex is empty
    },
    function(color, context)
    {
      alert('"Cancel" Button Clicked');
    });      
  $('#LiveButton').click(
    function()
    {
      $.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('hex', 'e2ddcf', this);
    });

});
```

thx

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, (a) a single pick changes bg-color of several elements or (b) each of several elements can be color picked individually?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but might be helpful for others. If you want to set same property with same value for multiple elements simply add the class id (comma separated).

```
    $('#Id1, .class1, .class2, #AnotherId').css(
    {
      backgroundColor: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
    });
```

But if you want to set separate properties or with separate values, make separate calls.

```
    $('#Id1').css(
    {
      backgroundColor: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
    });



    $('.someClass').css(
    {
      color: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
    });
```

As .css is expecting an array of css values you can also apply multiple changes to the same element in the same call.

```
    $('#Id1').css(
    {
      //Note the trailing comma except the last entry
      backgroundColor: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent',
      color: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
    });
```

Hope that helps.